# How to get the response body spring integration advice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

i have an outbound gateway. to handle exceptions I have added an advice chain,

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channelOutbound")
    @Bean
    public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler outboundEpay() {
        final HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
                endpoint);
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(String.class);
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        handler.setOutputChannelName("channelReply");
        handler.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(advice()));
        return handler;
    }

 @Bean
    public Advice advice() {
        final ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setFailureChannelName("channelAdvice");
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload");
        advice.setTrapException(true);
        return advice;
    }
```

when the API which is connected by the outbound gateway returns 200, everything works as expected. but when the API returns 500 status, an exception is thrown and the service activator connected to "channelAdvice" gets that. but I want to get the response body returned by the API along with 500 status. What should I do to get that response in advice?

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "channelAdvice")
    public void activatorAdvice(Message<?> message) {
//HERE
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` has a logic like this when exception is thrown in the `RestTemplate`:

```
case SERVER_ERROR:
                throw HttpServerErrorException.create(message, statusCode, statusText, headers, body, charset);
```

So, an `HttpServerErrorException` thrown by the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` has a `responseBody` property. That's the way for you to extract that body for error from a `ErrorMessage` sent to your `channelAdvice`.

Consider to debug your `activatorAdvice()` method to see a content of that `message` argument.

The logic in the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` is:

```
catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new MessageHandlingException(requestMessage,
                "HTTP request execution failed for URI [" + uri + "] in the [" + this + ']', e);
    }
```

So, that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` catches it and does this for sending an `ErrorMessage` :

```
MessagingException messagingException =
                new MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException(message, "Handler Failed",
                        unwrapThrowableIfNecessary(exception), evalResult);
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(messagingException);
        this.messagingTemplate.send(this.failureChannel, errorMessage);
```

Therefore `ErrorMessage` for your service activator contains `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException` as a `payload` and with a cause as a `HttpServerErrorException`.